# Three activity, two buttons and one answer

Tags: java, android

So i have one question:
I have to make program which will do;
In first activity we have one button, when we click it it opens a new activity, there we have a new button and we click it it open a third actiivty where we can se our total - how many times we clicked a buttons ( So: 2 times)

I know how to start new activity but i don't know **how to get number of clicks into the total.**

""Sorry for my bad english""

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to do this is to set the onClick() of the buttons to start a new activity by passing the incremented number as a [bundle](http://thedevelopersinfo.wordpress.com/2009/10/15/passing-data-between-activities-in-android/). Then, in the new activity, you can retrieve that data back from the passed in bundle by accessing its key and storing that in a variable.

You can then repeat this process similarly for the next activity.

Answer (score 1):

There is two simple ways of doing it. The simplest, which I'm assuming you want because it sounds like homework, is to just create a `static` field, maybe in a class to hold this field. Then in each `onClick()` simple increment the counter.

The other way would be to create a [SharedPreference](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref) and access a field in there everytime to increment. This will be persistent even if you close the app.

Answer (score 1):

you can have a static int variable. Set it to 1 in the on create of the first activity. Increment the variable by 1 in the onCreate of every activity. Decrement it by 1 in every onDestroy! this should give you the number of active Activities!

If you don't want just the active activities, then don't decrement it in the onDestroy!